# ffmpeg - resize video and merge with image

Tags: ffmpeg

[image: Attached Image]

I've 3 inputs (1st, 2nd and 3rd block)
1st a mp4 video with 600x400 aspect ratio
2nd a png image with 600x400 aspect ratio
3rd a jpeg image with red background

Output (4th block)

I need a mp4 video of 600x400 as output, it should have resized video of 422x282 and merge all three as shown in image.

Can we implement this via ffmpeg command line?
I'm able to resize video and image separately but having issue in creating desire output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i red.jpg -i frame.png
       -filter_complex "[0]scale=422:-1[vid];[1][vid]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[bg];
                        [bg][2]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2"   out.mp4
```

First, the video is resized. Then that resized video is overlaid on the red background. Then, on top of that result, the PNG frame is overlaid.

---

With no red frame and white BG,

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i frame.png
       -filter_complex "[0]scale=422:-1,pad=600:400:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=white[vid];[vid][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2"   out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks @Gyan for your answer, can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: what will be parameters if we skip red.jpg and continue with only 2 inputs?

Comment: What will act as canvas?

Comment: frame.png will act as canvas, but it should be top layer.

Comment: It can't. Bottom layer acts as canvas in overlay. What should BG color be?

Comment: we can use white color as bg

Comment: we're resizing video to 422:-1 and putting it at center. Can we put at specific location. like 10px from left and 20px from top? If yes, what will be command? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be correct command?  
`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i frame.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=422:-1,pad=600:400:10:20:color=white[vid];[vid][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" out.mp4`